# Change MySQL connection of Laravel migrate command

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, migration

I'm using laravel 5 and I have problem with migrations. The migrate command has a --database option but I want also to add an user option for example --user.

Or is it possible to add dynamically a mysql connection and let the migrate command use this connection and how to do this.

Thank you for helping out.

Comment: As far as i know, you can't do that. The application is working with what you have configured in your `.ENV` file, and in the `config/database.php` file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an alternative connection (that you have to define in config/database.php) in your migration. From the docs:

```
Schema::connection('foo')->create('users', function ($table) {
    $table->increments('id');
});
```

There is also a package, [laravel-custom-migrations](https://github.com/codengine/laravel-custom-migrations) that could help you in configuring migrations with dynamic connections. It could also provide a starting point if you want to create the --user option for migrate commands.