# Laravel migration get connection value from env throws Expression is not allowed as field default value

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables, database-migration

I've generated quite lots of migration files. As you know, I've got both development and production databases (even multiple ones).

Inside the migration file, you got the `protected $connection` definition

```php
<?php 
//...
return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * The database connection that should be used by the migration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $connection = 'dev_conn';
```

The problem comes when I want to change the connection "dynamically" or more efficiently:

```php
<?php 
//...
return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * The database connection that should be used by the migration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $connection = env('DB_CONNECTION');
```

But I get the following error.

> Expression is not allowed as field default value

Then, it'd be so annoying to change all the files one by one to:

```php
<?php 
//...
return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * The database connection that should be used by the migration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $connection = 'prod_conn';
```

Then how can I change the connection name in just one line of code, instead of changing every file???

Comment: Class properties can only be initialized with static values. In order to use `env` to set the value, you'll have to add it to a `__construct` function

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40738503/change-mysql-connection-of-laravel-migrate-command also has information how you can dynamically set the connection

Answer (score 1):

```
class CustomMigration extends Migration {
  protected $connection = null;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->connection = env('DB_CONNECTION');
  }
}
```

You cannot set a local property to a function like that in any PHP file, but you should be able to set it in the `__construct()` method.

You'll just have to make sure any "dynamic" migrations extend this Class instead of the default:

```
class CreateExampleTable extends CustomMigration {
  // ...
}
```

You might need to put this `CustomMigration` class in a different folder, to prevent Laravel trying to run it as a Migration, and apply an appropriate Namespace, but otherwise, this should work.

Comment: `$this->connection = env('DB_CONNECTION');` then if I check `dd($this->connection)` throws null.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple database connections are primarily used if you need to use multiple databases on one environment.

Its better to use environment variables to use a different database on development and production